Display Text in SDL2 and C++
I am making a blackjack game using SDL2 and C++. I want to print text to the screen using SDL_ttf. My code compiles but does not display text to the screen.
SDL_Surface* display = NULL;
TTF_Font* font;
font = TTF_OpenFont("C:\\Users\\Owner\\source\\repos\\Project94\\Debug\\Arial.ttf", 12);
SDL_Surface* text;
SDL_Color text_color = { 255,255,255 };
text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Hello", text_color);
SDL_BlitSurface(text, NULL, display, NULL);


Please add a [mcve], aka a complete program we can run ourselves.

I have finally got text to display to the screen.

SDL_Rect score_one;
score_one.x = 800;
score_one.y = 600;

int score = 0;
char buffer[50];
sprintf_s(buffer, "%d", score);
SDL_Surface* screen=NULL;
SDL_Surface* surface=NULL;
SDL_Color textColor = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };

surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, buffer, textColor);
SDL_BlitSurface(surface, NULL, gScreenSurface, &score_one);


This code prints numbers to the screen

Good job solving your own problem. This answer would be more useful if you added the remainder of the code to display it on the screen and provided a few helpful tips that helped you solve the problem. Code-only answers are discouraged because they are not that helpful to others that may find your answer. If you can improve your answer a little, drop a comment below letting me know and I'll come back and vote for it. Good job. (I'm not your downvote, but I suspect it was for the reasons I outline above)

I am using this code for a blackjack game where a score text tells how much the players hand is worth. I found it helpful  to solve this problem by using the SDL_BlitSurface function to draw text to the screen. Also the sprintf_s command was useful in converting a number into a character which can be drawn to the screen.

I understand, but that is why you should create A Minimal Complete Reproducible Example for your answer. I promise you, it will be much more well received on StackOverflow, along with your comments, than a partial code-only answer. I'm really just trying to help you out. When I started, I didn't like receiving downvotes on answers I worked hard to post. I suspect you are the same way. By small improvements you can greatly improve the quality of your answer. Good luck.
